# If Laplace's Equation is rotation invariant, why does the equation in polar coordinates involves partial derivatives with respect to $\theta$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

If Laplace's Equation
$$u_{xx}+u_{yy}=0$$
is rotation invariant (i.e. depends only on the radial variable $r$), why does the equation in polar coordinates
$$u_{rr}+\frac{1}{r}u_r+\frac{1}{r^2}u_{\theta\theta}=0$$
still contains the term $u_{\theta\theta}$?

Does the domain of the problem play a role here?

Comment: Can you rewrite your question? Does &u& means $u$? Otherwise, it will be helpful if you write down the laplace expression in polar coodinates in order to clarify your question.

Comment: I edited it a bit!

Comment: 'Rotation invariant' means it'll have the same form in a rotated system, that's all, not 'depends only on the radial variable $r$.' Good luck in your studies.

Comment: Thanks for the response. If it still depends on $\theta$, how come the derivation of its fundamental solution assumes that $u$ depends only on the radial variable $r$ and not $\theta$? And what does it mean that ''it'll have the same form in a rotated system''? Clearly the equation does not have the same form in Cartesian and Polar.

Comment: @user210190, in polar coordinates a rotation is a map such as $(r,\theta)\mapsto (r,\theta+\alpha)$, where $\alpha$ is the rotation angle, thus, let $A(r,\theta)$ be such rotation map, then defines $$u(r,\theta)=(v\circ A)(r,\theta).$$ If $(s,\phi)=A(r,\theta)$, show that $u_r=v_s$, $u_{rr}=v_{ss}$ and $u_\theta=v_\phi$, thus the Laplace Equation is the same! (Just relabeling the variables)

Answer (score 4):

That the equation is rotation invariant does not impose that all solutions are rotation invariant. It just says that any solution, after being rotated, is still a solution. If the boundary conditions are also rotation-invariant, you can take any solution and average over all of its rotated versions to get an angle-independent solution.

Another point-of-view is that one can try to construct solutions as linear combinations of separable products, where one factor only depends on the radius and one only on the angle. If the single terms are also solutions, you get separate equations for the angle and the radius factor function, resulting in scalar eigenvalue problems that are coupled via the eigenvalue.

Comment: Thanks, that makes more sense. Juts to be sure I understand. So, suppose I have a solution $u$ and the domain of the problem is some region $D$. Then suppose I let $U$ be $u$ rotated and $D'$ be $D$ rotated in the same way. Then $U$ will also be a solution on its rotated domain $D'$?

Comment: Yes. If the boundary condition has normal derivative, these need to be explicitly rotated too.

Answer (score 1):

The second equation does not depend "explicitly" on $\theta$. As a consequence, if $u=u_0(r,\theta)$ is a solution, then so is $u=u_0(r,\theta+\epsilon)$, for any $\epsilon$. However, since there is a $r$ in the equation, it is not true that  $u=u_0(r+\epsilon,\theta)$ is also a solution.